# How to create an aab file in apache cordova?

Tags: cordova, apk, android-app-bundle

i have an apache cordova project but i want to build an aab file not apk,please help

In apache cordova ive used this command
cordova run android
to create an apk but i want an aab file instead

Answer (score 6):

You should build your app using

```
cordova build android --release -- --packageType=bundle
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `cordova build android --release -- --keystore=ABC.keystore --storePassword=123 --alias=ABC --password=123 --packageType=bundle`
2. `cd platforms/android`
3. `./gradlew bundleRelease`
4. Take a look into `platforms/android/app/build` and you'll find `.apk` file in `apk` folder as well as `.aab` in `bundle/release`.

Answer (score 0):

I used android studio to sign my apps and create aab files